# How to get all items from a GtkComboBoxText in GTK4 (Rust, GTK-Rs)?

Tags: rust, gtk4, gtk-rs

What I wanna do is set the selected item in ComboboxText. I know that should be done using `set_active()` method, but that requires a position (index). All I have is the selected value (string).

So I think I should iterate over all the items and find the position of the right one this way. Is this correct? Or is there a better way to do this?

How can I obtain a list of the items?

```
let combo: ComboBoxText = self.widget.clone().downcast::<ComboBoxText>().unwrap();
let model = combo.model().unwrap();
// how to get an iterator here?
```

Comment: I'm no expect on gtk-rs, but since `ComboBoxText` implements `IsA<ComboBox>`, and `ComboBox` has a `active-id` property, isn't that exactly what you need?

Comment: Also, FYI, `ComboBox` and `ComboBoxText` are marked as `deprecated`, the docs point you to using `DropDown` instead.

Comment: @JMAA I know it's deprecated but my app supports it. Moreover, setting the active-id doesn't seem to wok. At least, it doesn't work with the string value of the option. And get_active_id() returns None even when an option is sleceted.